# JS style.cssText only working with setTimeout function

Tags: javascript

```
    function varStart(){
    var timing1 = setTimeout(hideAll,1000);  //working
    hideAll();  //not working
}
    function hideAll(){
    var element1 = document.getElementById("header");
    element1.style.cssText="Opacity:0.0;";
}

<html>
    <title>test</title>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
        <script src="js/api.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            varStart();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            <img src="images/header.png">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

all i wanted to do is to make the header invisible on load and be visible after some time, the 2 functions are in "js/script.js"

Comment: Please provide a runnable [mcve] that demonstrates the issue including where you call `varStart()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should execute your code after document is loaded.

```
document.onload = hideAll;

function hideAll(){
    var element1 = document.getElementById("header");
    element1.style.cssText="Opacity:0.0;";
}
```

Comment: i have tried, unfortunately doesn't work for me, i have added the html part in my post, maybe there's a problem there i don't know